# Вопрос по .htaccess подскажите в чём суть этих двух строк, они же вроде ничего не делают ровным счетом

Tags: .htaccess

Собственно строки:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался. Данный код удалял слеш с конца адресной строки и делал 301-й редирект на адрес без слеша.